# Connect returns -1 with getaddrinfo on client side

Tags: c, linux, client-server, connect, tcp

I'm running a client and server code on Linux.

The server uses TCP/IP with `AF_INET` and `SOCK_STREAM` protocol.

At first, at the client side, I (wrongly?) used `bind` to get the correct `addr_info` from the linked list that is returned by `getaddrinfo`, returning the appropriate sockaddr_in. I had a method that looked like that at the client side:

```
struct sockaddr_in *hostname_to_ip(char *hostname, struct addrinfo *servinfo)
{ 
    int check_sfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *p;
    //struct sockaddr_in* ret_value;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    int res = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &servinfo) 
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: error in getaddrinfo on hostname: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // getaddrinfo returned a linked list of relevant addresses
    // loop through the addresses and return the first one available
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        check_sfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (checksfd < 0)
            continue;

        if (bind(check_sfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0) { // bind successful
            return (struct sockaddr_in*) p->ai_addr;
        }
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

later connecting to the returned value in connect.

The form of the code worked well and connection between the client and server was established successfully (and all functionality worked). However, I had memory leakages due to not using `freeaddrinfo` correctly.

So I decided to change the code to the following:

```
void hostname_to_ip(char *hostname, int *connection)
{ 
    int check_sfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *p, *servinfo;
    //struct sockaddr_in* ret_value;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;

    int res = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &servinfo) 
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: error in getaddrinfo on hostname: %s\n", gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // getaddrinfo returned a linked list of relevant addresses
    // loop through the addresses and return the first one available
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        check_sfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (check_sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(check_sfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen) == 0) { // connection successful
        *connection = check_sfd;
        break;
        }

        close(check_sfd);
    }

    if (p == NULL) {
        // print error
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     }

    freeaddrinfo(&servinfo);
}
```

However, now I can't seem to connect to the server, as `connect` always returns -1 (`p` starts as non-`NULL`, so the connection to the socket just fails). The error is `connection refused`.

When I change the `ai_socktype` to `SOCK_DGRAM` the connection is successful but the client fails later when sending the data (makes sense since the server is using `SOCK_STREAM`), which is pretty weird.

Any ideas? The code of the client and server is pretty long so I didn't attached all of it, but I tried to add all the relevant information. If anything is missing, comment and I'll add it.

This is the `strace` info on the client:

```
execve("./pcc_client", ["./pcc_client", "localhost", "2001", "1000"], [/* 71 vars */]) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2446000
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88205, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 88205, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0a0f4fa000
close(3)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\2\1\1\3\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0P\t\2\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=1868984, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a0f4f9000
mmap(NULL, 3971488, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7f0a0ef21000
mprotect(0x7f0a0f0e1000, 2097152, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0a0f2e1000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1c0000) = 0x7f0a0f2e1000
mmap(0x7f0a0f2e7000, 14752, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a0f2e7000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a0f4f8000
mmap(NULL, 4096, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a0f4f7000
arch_prctl(ARCH_SET_FS, 0x7f0a0f4f8700) = 0
mprotect(0x7f0a0f2e1000, 16384, PROT_READ) = 0
mprotect(0x601000, 4096, PROT_READ)     = 0
mprotect(0x7f0a0f510000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f0a0f4fa000, 88205)           = 0
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 3
getsockname(3, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(0), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, [16]) = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
socket(PF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0) = 4
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_LOCAL, sun_path="/var/run/nscd/socket"}, 110) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
close(4)                                = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x2446000
brk(0x2467000)                          = 0x2467000
open("/etc/nsswitch.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=529, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# /etc/nsswitch.conf\n#\n# Example"..., 4096) = 529
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/host.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=92, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# The \"order\" line is only used "..., 4096) = 92
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
getpid()                                = 12014
open("/etc/resolv.conf", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=184, ...}) = 0
read(4, "# Dynamic resolv.conf(5) file fo"..., 4096) = 184
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=88205, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 88205, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 4, 0) = 0x7f0a0f4fa000
close(4)                                = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.nohwcap", F_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 4
read(4, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\260!\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=47600, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 2168600, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0) = 0x7f0a0ed0f000
mprotect(0x7f0a0ed1a000, 2093056, PROT_NONE) = 0
mmap(0x7f0a0ef19000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 4, 0xa000) = 0x7f0a0ef19000
mmap(0x7f0a0ef1b000, 22296, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7f0a0ef1b000
close(4)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f0a0ef19000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f0a0f4fa000, 88205)           = 0
open("/etc/hosts", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC)  = 4
fstat(4, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=233, ...}) = 0
read(4, "127.0.0.1\tlocalhost\n127.0.1.1\tmi"..., 4096) = 233
read(4, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(4)                                = 0
fstat(1, {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(136, 2), ...}) = 0
write(1, "x\n", 2x
)                      = 2
socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP) = 4
write(1, "4\n", 24
)                      = 2
write(1, "\n", 1
)                       = 1
connect(4, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53511), sin_addr=inet_addr("127.0.0.1")}, 16) = -1 ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
close(4)                                = 0
write(1, "Error: couldn't connect to hostn"..., 56Error: couldn't connect to hostname. Connection refused
) = 56
exit_group(1)                           = ?
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if this is actually your problem, but when `connect` fails you need to close `check_sfd`.  (Also, in one place you have a typo `checksfd`, but I doubt that's in your real code or it wouldn't compile.)

Comment: @zwol yes you are right about both. I actually do the `close(check_sfd)` at the code, just forgot to add it here. The typo is only here as well, thanks

Comment: @MarkPlotnick sorry, this is a typo here as well. it is `==` in the code. I'll edit it

Comment: The sockaddr passed to `connect` needs to have a valid port number. "Connection refused" means "the destination is running IP but there's nothing listening on the port you specified". Can you either print out the sockaddr or run `strace` on your program to show what's actually being passed to `connect`?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick ok, how do I solve it? I know the port number. I tried casting the `sockaddr` to `sockaddr_in` and changing the port number (and then casting back to `sockaddr` for `connect`) but that didn't help.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Ok. I fixed it. Indeed it was a problem with the port number. When I added the change with the casting to `sockaddr_in` I used `htonl` instead of `htons`. Thanks a lot for your help. You can answer with detail and I'll accept :

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your fix for the problem will work as long as the compiler cooperates and you don't need to support IPv6.  But a better fix is to pass the port number to `getaddrinfo` in the first place, as the "service" argument.  You have to convert it to a string to do that, but you can go back to using `AF_UNSPEC` and not having to cast or manipulate the sockaddrs in `getaddrinfo`'s return list at all:

```
void hostname_to_ip(char *hostname, int *connection_socket,
                    unsigned short port_number)
{
    int check_sfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *p, *servinfo;
    char port_number_s[sizeof("65535")];

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = AI_NUMERICSERV;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    snprintf(port_number_s, sizeof port_number_s, "%u", port_number);

    int res = getaddrinfo(hostname, port_number_s, &hints, &servinfo);
    if (res == EAI_SYSTEM) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error looking up %s: %s\n",
                hostname, strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    } else if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error looking up %s: %s\n",
                hostname, gai_strerror(res));
        exit(1);
    } else if (servinfo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error looking up %s: No addresses found\n",
                hostname);
        exit(1);
    }

    // getaddrinfo returned a linked list of relevant addresses
    // loop through the addresses and return the first one we can connect to
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        check_sfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (check_sfd == -1)
            continue;

        if (connect(check_sfd, p->ai_addr, p->ai_addrlen)) {
            *connection_socket = check_sfd;
            freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
            return;
        }
        close(check_sfd);
    }
    // If we get here, we couldn't connect to any of the addresses.
    fprintf(stderr, "Couldn't connect to %s: %s\n", hostname, strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
}
```

I also fixed some other subtle bugs:

- `port_number` should be `unsigned short` because that's what it is in TCP.
- If `getaddrinfo` returns `EAI_SYSTEM`, you need to print `strerror(errno)` instead of `gai_strerror(res)`.
- On some systems, `getaddrinfo` can claim to have succeeded but return zero addresses.
- Always print the hostname of the peer you're trying to talk to, in error messages about connecting to the network.  Same principle as always printing the filename when a file operation fails.
- If you use an early return inside the loop when `connect` succeeds, you don't need to check again for success after the loop.   It's not necessary to free memory when you're about to print an error message and exit.

Follow-up exercises for you, in ascending order of difficulty:

- It would be better to return -1 on failure or the open socket on success, instead of writing to an out-parameter or exiting the program.
- Use `getnameinfo` to print "Connecting to 128.52.0.2..." messages like `telnet` does.
- Use nonblocking sockets to connect to all the addresses at once, then use `select` or `poll` (your choice) to get the first one that works and close all the others.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarkPlotnick, I figured out that the problem was related to an unset (or wrongly set) port number for the returning address in the linked list. The following update to the code fixed it (as I know the port number at the time the function is called):

```
void hostname_to_ip(char *hostname, int *connection_socket, int port_number)
{ 
    int check_sfd;
    struct addrinfo hints, *p, *servinfo;

    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;//AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_STREAM;
    hints.ai_flags = 0;
    hints.ai_protocol = 0;

    int res = getaddrinfo(hostname, NULL, &hints, &servinfo);
    if (res != 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: error in getaddrinfo on hostname: %s\n", gai_strerror(res));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // getaddrinfo returned a linked list of relevant addresses
    // loop through the addresses and return the first one available
    for (p = servinfo; p != NULL; p = p->ai_next) {
        check_sfd = socket(p->ai_family, p->ai_socktype, p->ai_protocol);
        if (check_sfd == -1)
            continue;

        struct sockaddr_in *sockstruct = (struct sockaddr_in*) p->ai_addr;
        sockstruct->sin_port = htons(port_number);
        sockstruct->sin_family = AF_INET;
        socklen_t addrsize = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

        if (connect(check_sfd, (struct sockaddr*)sockstruct, addrsize) != -1) { // successfuly connected
            *connection_socket = check_sfd;
            break;
        }

        close(check_sfd);
    }

    if (p == NULL) { // couldn't connect to any item in the linked list
        printf("Error: couldn't connect to hostname. %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);
}
```